# Plpgsql: How can i perform the following task in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql

--Syntax in SQL Server

```
SET @InnerQuery = @InnerQuery  + N'SELECT * from [' + @TableName + '] UNION ALL';
```

--Here i am trying in plpgsql for above query.

```
innerquery:= innerquery UNION ALL select * from '%',TableName; --Not in working state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
execute innerQuery || ' union all select * from "'
    || tableName || '"';
```

Comment: You forgot a SQL injection sanitization - quote_ident(tableName)

Comment: Still getting an error.ERROR: syntax error at or near "union"

LINE 1: union all select * from "tbl12"

Comment: It depends what `innerQuery` is set to. If it's blank, of course you'll get that error, because the resulting SQL string starts with `union all`. I just translated your SQL Server code to postgres. I have no idea what value you are assigning to `innerQuery`,

Comment: Absolutely right. Thank you so much Bohemian. I got it.